# How to style in-page scrollbar without changing browser scrollbar?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a scrollable div that uses overflow: scroll.

I want to style the scrollbar in this div, but the styles I added also changes the browser scrollbar. How do I adjust it so that only the in-page scrollbar changes?

**Note**: please test in Chrome as that's what I've tested so far, the scrollbar styles don't work in Firefox.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMdBQQ

**CSS**:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ADADAD;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #ADADAD;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class `.scroll` before the -webkit code

```
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white; 
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background: #ADADAD;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #ADADAD;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply limit it to the .scroll element, like this:

```
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxdgmq

Answer (score 1):

This might be kinda tricky, cause it depends on browser. Usually people draw their own "scroll-bar" with div elements (using JS to describe its behaviour) and real scroll-bar they hide adding `~22px` to block width and add CSS  property `overflow: scroll-y`.

**UPDATE:**
I've found for you some [simple scripts](http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/top-7-custom-scrollbar-javascript-and-jquery-plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

.scroll Will needed to be added first.
Or it will register as this

```css
:root::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}

:root::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white; 
}

:root::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ADADAD;
}

:root::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #ADADAD;
}
/*Nothing to do with this*/
:root {
font-size: 200px
}
```

```html
<p>Hi! This will not register once as a scrollbar.<br><br>It's going to register as:
:root::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}

:root::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white; 
}

:root::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ADADAD;
}

:root::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #ADADAD;
}
</p>
```

For making it for the `.scroll class`
we will have to do this:

```css
/*nothing to do with this*/
.scroll {
height: 80px;
font-size: 100px;
background: red;
overflow: auto;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: white; 
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ADADAD;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #ADADAD;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
Hi,
<br>
This will register for 
<br >
a styled scrollbar in HTML, and CSS.
<br />
With the class scroll(.scroll)
</div>
```

[CSS scrollbar styling - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/)

CodePen: https://codepen.io/CatMan10/pen/yQjqaM

Comment: @souzan Please May you tell me if this helped you?